# Karaf doesn't start

Tags: maven, apache-karaf

I'm learning Karaf, following this tutorial: https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist

I build it as requested. Then I attempt to start karaf like this:

`./bin/karaf` from where I exported binaries. In response I get:
`Could not resolve mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework/5.6.10`

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the content of log:

`Mar 03, 2018 3:56:01 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main main
SEVERE: Could not launch framework
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework/5.6.10
    at org.apache.karaf.main.util.SimpleMavenResolver.resolve(SimpleMavenResolver.java:59)
    at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.createClassLoader(Main.java:466)
    at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.launch(Main.java:253)
    at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.main(Main.java:178)`

Comment: I am confused by "Then I attempt to start karaf from where I exported binaries". Starting Apache Karaf by `./bin/karaf` is completely correct I think. Maybe try to download Karaf to a different location and try to start it first without any connection to the tutorial? This should work.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue?

Answer (score 3):

It's a kind of black magic.

You have to use -z option while unpacking karaf tar package, like "tar -xvzf ......."

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when I used 'mc' to unzip karaf archive file.

1. During unarchiving I was getting a message about duplicate file in examples directory.
   [image]
2. Karaf was getting broken, refusing to start because of missing dependencies.

The issue was resolved when I used **tar command line**

```
tar -C /opt/ -xvzf apache-karaf-4.2.9.tar.gz
```

You can  compare directories that were unzipped using different ways below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Could not resolve mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework/5.6.10:

means that the dependencies of the framework Apache Felix are missed from your karaf directory.

To resolve this framework you will need to provide all the dependencies (jar files) or you can simply download the complete installation folder from [here](https://karaf.apache.org/download.html)